# What is a good method for creating a guide for standardized markup?

Tags: looking-for-a-script, markup, wiki, guide

I need to create a guide or wiki that outlines different standardized techniques for marking up reusable elements in our software. When adding new features our developers are often able to reuse or mimic existing markup, and I'd like to make this as easy as possible for them. In order to do this now they have to dig through the interface to find something that's close enough.

Are there any good examples online that show code samples for standardized markup?

Is there a tool (wiki, etc.) that would make this somewhat easy to create?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'marking up reusable elements' a
nd 'standardized markup'? 
Do you mean reusing code (i.e. snippets of logic/functionality) or reusing UI elements?

Comment: Reusable code, essentially. Standards for marking up different UI elements (forms, tables, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

You may wish to consider a code snippet collection sharing service such as [Smipple](http://www.smipple.net/), [Code Barrel](http://www.codebarrel.com/), or [CodePad Projects](http://codepad.org/mkproj). They're designed for teams to share code/markup; some (e.g. Code Barrel) allow you to tag snippets, which may help your team organise them by UI element.